# Jquery internet explorer 9 problems

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have problems with Ie 9 and Jquery. I thought the newest Jquery is compatible with Ie 9 but some default functions does not work in IE 9. Does anybody had the same problems and know how to solve it. The folowing triggers does work in IE 10 but not in IE 9:

```
$('.uitklappen').click(function(event){

$('.leermiddel_check').on('click',function(event){
```

Thanks!

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// FUNCTIES

  // De romein wat laten zeggen
  function romein(zin){
    $('.spreekwolkje').html(zin);     
  }

 // functie voor ophalen van levels of domeinen
 function getObjects(){

    var type = $('.keuze option:checked').text();
    $('.objecten').empty();
    $('.progress').css('display','');
    $.ajax({type: "POST",async:false,url: base_url+"aanhetwerk/get/"+type+"/",
        success: 
        function(data){
          $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(i,item)
          {
             $('.objecten').append('<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.naam+'</option>');                 
          });
          $('.progress').css('display','none');             
    }});            

    if ($(".object_keuze").length > 0){
        $('select[name=objecten] option[value='+$(".object_keuze").val()+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
    }   
 }        


// Functie om de kop selectie op te slaan en door te laden
function saveKoppen(){

    // Doorloop alle gecheckte koppen
    var array = new Array(); var count = 0;
    $('#filter').find('.check_kop').each(function( index ) {
        if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
            array[count] = $(this).attr('id');
            count++;
        }
    });

    $.ajax({type: "POST",
            async:true,
            url: base_url+"aanhetwerk/opslaankoppen/",
            data:{koppen:array}
    });
}

// Functie om onderdelen te hiden
function hideOnderdelen(){
    $('#filter').find('.check_kop').each(function( index ) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if($(this).prop('checked') == false){               
            $('.kop_block[id='+id+']').hide();
        }else{
            $('.kop_block[id='+id+']').show();
        }
    });
}

// UITVOEREN BIJ TRIGGER
  // Uitklappen van leermiddelen
  $('.uitklappen').click(function(event){
    console.log($(this).closest('div'));
    if($(this).closest('tr').find('table').is(":visible")){
        $(this).closest('tr').find('table').hide();
        $(this).find('img').attr('src',base_url+'external/images/icoontjes/FatCow_Icons16x16/toggle_expand.png');   
    }else{
        $(this).closest('tr').find('table').show();
        $(this).find('img').attr('src',base_url+'external/images/icoontjes/FatCow_Icons16x16/toggle.png');                  
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  // Leerdoel checken en unchecken
  $('.leerdoel_check').on('click',function(event){
    var leerdoel_id = $(this).attr('id');

    if($(this).hasClass('unchecked')){

        var d = new Date();
        var month = d.getMonth()+1;
        var day = d.getDate();
        var year = d.getFullYear();
        var minutes = d.getMinutes();
        var hours = d.getUTCHours();

        $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').html(day+'-'+month+'-'+year+' '+hours+':'+minutes);

        $(this).removeClass('unchecked').addClass('checked');
        $.ajax({type: "POST",url: base_url+"aanhetwerk/checkLeerdoel/"+leerdoel_id+"/1/"});   

        // Melding geven aan Romein
        var min = 0; var max = 7;           
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        if(random == 0){ romein('');}
        if(random == 1){ romein('Weer wat geleerd. Ga zo door.');}
        if(random == 2){ romein('Ik ben trots op je!');}
        if(random == 3){ romein('Ja, ja alweer een nieuw leerdoel afgevinkt.');}
        if(random == 4){ romein('Aaah hier word ik blij van. ');}
        if(random == 5){ romein('');}   
        if(random == 6){ romein('Ik zal eens een leuke mop vertellen: ""WOW jij bent lang, je doet vast aan basketbal!" "WOW jij bent klein, je doet vast aan minigolf?""');}
        if(random == 7){ romein('Nu verdien jij een leuke mop: "Ben je sportief?" "Ja! Ik surf..... Op internet!" HAHAHAH');}

    }else{
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').html('');
        $(this).removeClass('checked').addClass('unchecked');
        $.ajax({type: "POST",url: base_url+"aanhetwerk/checkLeerdoel/"+leerdoel_id+"/0/"});   
    }

    event.preventDefault();
  });

  // Leermiddel checken en unchecken
  $('.leermiddel_check').on('click',function(event){
    var leermiddel_id = $(this).attr('id');
    if($(this).hasClass('unchecked-l')){
        $(this).removeClass('unchecked-l').addClass('checked-l');
        $.ajax({type: "POST",url: base_url+"aanhetwerk/checkLeermiddel/"+leermiddel_id+"/1/"});     
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass('checked-l').addClass('unchecked-l');
        $.ajax({type: "POST",url: base_url+"aanhetwerk/checkLeermiddel/"+leermiddel_id+"/0/"});  
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  });             

  // Expert modus aan of uit
  $('.expertbutton').on('click',function(event){
    var leerdoel_id = $(this).attr('id');
    if($(this).hasClass('non-expert')){
        $(this).removeClass('non-expert').addClass('expert');
        $.ajax({type: "POST",url: base_url+"aanhetwerk/setExpert/"+leerdoel_id+"/1/"});
        // Melding geven aan Romein
        var min = 0; var max = 3;           
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        if(random == 0){ romein('Jij bent een echte topper!');}
        if(random == 1){ romein('');}
        if(random == 2){ romein('Wat fijn dat je anderen wilt helpen');}
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass('expert').addClass('non-expert');
        $.ajax({type: "POST",url: base_url+"aanhetwerk/setExpert/"+leerdoel_id+"/0/"});
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  });   

// Expert modus aan of uit
$('.expert').change(function(event){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({type: "POST",url: base_url+"aanhetwerk/expertModusOn/"+value+"/"});   
    event.preventDefault();     
}); 

$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
$( "#dialog" ).dialog('close');
// Open expert scherm
$('.experts').click(function(event){
    $(this).next('.laden').show();
    $('#dialog ul').empty();
    var leerdoel_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async:false,
            url: base_url+"aanhetwerk/getExperts/"+leerdoel_id+"/",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(i,item){
                    $('#dialog ul').append('<li><a class="user-icon"></a>'+item.naam+'</li>');
                });
            }           
        });  
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog('open');
    $(this).next('.laden').hide();
    event.preventDefault();
});

// Selecteer de option die voor de post was ingevoerd
if ($(".type_keuze").length > 0){
    $('select[name=type] option[value='+$(".type_keuze").val()+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
}

// FUNCTIES UITVOEREN
getObjects();
hideOnderdelen();

$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");  

// Aan het uitvinken van koppen
$('#aanhetwerk_content').on('click','.check_kop',function(){
    hideOnderdelen();   
    saveKoppen();       
});

// Bij wijzigen van de keuze objecten ophalen
$('.keuze').change(function(){
    getObjects();
});
```

});

Comment: what version is your "newest jQuery"?

Comment: test this, change function(event) to function(e)

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Do you get errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: please post your ful code , you may have another error inside page

Comment: take a look if you have any "console.log" statements in your code, execution in ie9 witout having developer toolbar open is not possible otherwise in many cases

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I use version 2.0.3. The full code is added

Comment: @ John Smith:Good point! I removed the console.log. But is does not make an difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery 2 **does not support** Internet Explorer 6-8. If you must have support for IE, use v1.9 or lower.